# Adding custom row-header to ui-grid

Tags: css, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I would like to create my own custom column to ui-grid, similiar to select column (column with check mark) on  attached picture:
[image]

Is this possible, what is easiest way to do this?

Comment: Could be this - http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/114_row_header

Comment: Yes, I have no idea how i missed that in documentation! Thank you.

Comment: @nurgasemetey could you outline the basics covered by the documentation and make that an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for this has been moved to [here](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/tutorial/Tutorial:%20114%20Adding%20a%20row%20header).
The basics are that you need to add the row header as a new column in the `onRegisterGridApi` property of your `gridOptions` object. The definition of which is the same as any other column (i.e. `ui.grid.class:GridOptions.columnDef`).

For example, if all your rows had a property you wanted to use as the row header, you could use a custom template like:

```html
<div class="ui-grid-row-header-cell ui-grid-disable-selection">
  <div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">{{row.entity['rowHeaderFieldName']}}</div>
</div>
```

Which you would assign to the `cellTemplate` property of your row header column definition